# Azure Devops: Creating a service connection to allow deploying to a single Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

According [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security) you can create a service connection to Azure which allows users to have access to all resource groups of the given subscription or limiting to a certain resource group:

> Resource Group: Leave empty to allow users to access all resources defined within the subscription, or select a resource group to which you want to restrict users' access (users will be able to access only the resources defined within that group).

So, if you want to give access to a certain webapp ONLY, the [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-with-an-existing-service-principal) option is to create a new service principal, give access to the resource and configure it on service connection.

Any way of doing this without creating a new service principal? I mean: It would be nice to have the option of selecting the resource (and not only the resource group) when creating a service connection with automated security, but obviously it´s not available.

We are planning to move a LOT of webapps (managed by different teams) to Azure and to create a new principal for each one (in order to guarantee the owner team as the only one allowed to deploy) seems not practical.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is impossible to restrict owner team only to deploy to a specific web app using service connection. For there is no way to restrict access to a specific web app in a resource group in azure devops service connection, except creating a new service principal for each web app.

Currently, you will have to create new service principle for each web app. You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click **suggest a feature** and choose **Azure devops**) to microsoft development team. Hope they will consider adding this feature in the future sprint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @levi. If I´m not wrong, once you have those credentials you could do the same with the IIS Web App Deploy, since internally it uses web deploy and seems that it allows azure webapp deploying [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2019#import-the-publish-settings-in-visual-studio-and-deploy). Does kudu provide any advantage over this method? Moreover, I assume that if those creds are managed by developer team no approval can be set to protect the resource (as you can do in service connections)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Kudu provides no advantage. You will have to create new service principle for each web app currently.